# Why doesn't Google's "new sign-in from X" email notification contain the IP of the computer that connected to my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

When someone connects to my Gmail account, I sometimes receive a "new sign-in from X" email notification from Google, which just indicates the OS and the timestamp of the connection.

Why doesn't it indicate the IP of the device that was used to connect as well? (that would make things easier for the actual Gmail account owner to know whether the connection came from one of its devices)

---

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think this an answer you will only be able to get from someone who works for Google. But I do have a few theories:

1. Google does not want to scare none technical users with a set of numbers they have no idea what they are.
2. Why show the IP when they can just show the location? Most users would probably look up the IP anyways so Google saves them time by showing them the location (I notice that in your notification it does not say the location but usually they do).

**Note**: If you ever want to see the IP's of any session that logged in, you can scroll to the bottom of the page on Gmail desktop version and on the bottom right under `"Last account activity"` click on `"details"`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm looking for theories (to understand possible reasonings leading to the decision on whether to disclose the IP). Regarding your point 1, I have added another screenshot that would scare the non-technical user, even without disclosing the IP. Regarding your point 2, the location is a good hint, but you're screwed if the attacker is close to you (which might happen in case of social engineering).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Exactly. I would assume they don't show the IP because they show the location which is what a person would check with the IP anyways.